# Error while using rtabmap with remote D435i input: TF_OLD_DATA

Tags: slam, navigation, 3dmapping, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm fairly new to ROS and apologize in advance if my question is stupid.

What I'm trying to do is to have a rover carrying a Pi and camera remote mapping its environment while the main computing is executed on my laptop.
To get a start I followed this installation guide: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/wiki/SLAM-with-D435i for realsense2_camera, imu_filter_madgwick, rtabmap_ros and robot_localization on the laptop only, launching the file included in the package, opensource_tracking.launch: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/blob/development/realsense2_camera/launch/opensource_tracking.launch. This worked fine.
The problem emerged when I moved some of the nodes to the Pi.

**Setup:**

-Intel RealSense D435i camera connected to Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian Buster, ROS Kinetic) with USB 3

-Laptop (Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic) currently connected to Pi via Ethernet

**What I did to distribute the nodes:**

-Splitting the launch file in two: only the first include block for rs_camera.launch is contained in the launch file on the Pi, the rest stays on the laptop

-In rs_camera.launch: Setting the frame rates to 6 (due to prior Error: UBS overflow)

-In rtabmap.launch: Setting queue_size=1000, rgbd_sync=true, compressed=true

**The Error:**

Now, when launching the launch file on the Pi, the system takes some time to stop throwing Errors, but after that the camera topics are available on the laptop. The output of launching it is rather long: https://pastebin.com/fUn4YZXQ

When I the proceed to launch on the laptop, this is the output: https://pastebin.com/2VNe1X5s

I have tried rviz and rtabmapviz, both just show an empty window without mapping

**What I have tried so far:**

I run roswtf on the laptop with the following result:

```
    Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

    WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
     * /rtabmap/rtabmap:

   * /rtabmap/initialpose
   * /gps/fix
   * /rtabmap/global_pose
   * /rtabmap/goal
   * /user_data_async
   * /rtabmap/goal_node
 * /ukf_se:
   * /example/twist
   * /set_pose
   * /example/another_odom
   * /example/pose
 * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz:
   * /rtabmap/goal_node
 * /rtabmap/republish_rgb:
   * /camera/color/image_raw/compressed
 * /rtabmap/republish_depth:
   * /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw/compressedDepth
```

I checked that both devices are synchronized to a ntp server.

Also, I plotted the transformation tree in both situations. First all nodes on the laptop and working:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17d9apd4X5hgDfStVPAXzHS-YawE5QCXn/view

And with distributed nodes:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XNniGe_CLSMmH-gLWrUEIGIz69tG_-7f/view

From reading on this forum I figured that the negative age of the transform from 'map' can be the problem an that hitting the reset button in rviz can help, however it doesn't in this case.
I also read that diving into the source code and looking for usages of time::now() to get the latest transform and change them could be a way. However I am afraid of screwing it all over as soon as I tinker around in the code that is working fine on a single machine.

Why is there no 'map' base link when operating distributed? Is the time I have to wait between the two launches a problem? Are there any other parameters I have to change in rtabmap? I am very grateful for every hint.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345363/error-while-using-rtabmap-with-remote-d435i-input:-tf_old_data/) by [Lisa514](https://answers.ros.org/users/52138/lisa514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On rtabmap side, image topics cannot be synchonized, from your second log:

```
[ WARN] [1582896218.176834702]: /rtabmap/rgbd_sync: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set.
/rtabmap/rgbd_sync subscribed to (approx sync):
   /camera/color/image_raw_relay,
   /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw_relay,
   /camera/color/camera_info
```

Do

```
rostopic hz /camera/color/image_raw_relay /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw_relay /camera/color/camera_info
```

to see if you are receiving all topics on your laptop. Those topics are created from relays launched by `rtabmap.launch` for convenience (to avoid multiple remote subscriptions). The actual topics to check are:

```
rostopic hz /camera/color/image_raw/compressed /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw/compressedDepth /camera/color/camera_info
```

Try this command on the laptop and on the RPI, to see the difference of frame rate. An issue could be that RPI has difficulty to compress all data, look at its CPU usage.

If you want to to use your robot odometry (from the `ukf_se` node), set `visual_odometry` to false and `odom_frame_id` to `odom` in `rtabmap.launch`. Note also that `approx_rgbd_sync` would be set to false for realsense data. You can keep`queue_size` set to default (10).

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Lisa,

This is a bit late but I ran into a similar error when running the realsense camera over the network. `rostopic hz my_topic` can be a bit misleading as if everything is set up correctly, they will all appear to be publishing correctly! I found that the error occurred when the network link could not support the data throughput required. I reckon this is because the latency becomes so high that the timestamps read as too old to use. I see you are using wired Ethernet, but even transmitting just the aligned depth image and RGB at 424x240 and 640x360 respectively, for me, takes 48.9MBps (That's megabytes, not bits, to be clear) over Ethernet. The Pi 4 is not capable of going over around 51MBps from my tests, at least in this use-case, but it may be my router that is the limiting factor. You may be able to get this working if you reduce the data throughput.

Try running `rs-enumerate-devices` and choosing the lowest resolution and FPS settings. For me `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch initial_reset:=true depth_width:=424 depth_height:=240 depth_fps:=15 color_width:=424 color_height:=240 color_fps:=15 align_depth:=true` only needs 22MBps. You can also lower the gyro and accelerometer FPS to 200 and 63 respectively.

As a sidenote, there is an issue with the gyro and accelerometer of the D435i, specifically on the Pi I believe, that causes them to simply stop publishing data after a while. There is an open ticket with Intel to look at it but it may be a while until this is fixed. If you have had any luck with getting this working let me know.

---

Originally posted by [ciarfah](https://answers.ros.org/users/72781/ciarfah/) with karma: 11 on 2021-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lisa514](https://answers.ros.org/users/52138/lisa514/) on 2021-04-02**:
Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer to my old post. I think you are right and have since come to the conclusion that link qualitiy and computing power were just insufficient. The Pi could not keep up with compressing the data. Trying to send uncompressed data however resulted in way too many package resend attempts. Either way the pi was at 100 percent all the time with tasks failing. I tried lower frame rates but they called for very slow movement to get a coherent point cloud, which quickly got unsustainable for my problem. Thank you very much anyway for your response.